# Identify index that is not shared between two variables in R

Tags: r, indexing

I would like to identify the indices for which there is not a match between two variables. The following code identifies the matches rather than the mismatched:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- c("a", "z", "c")
which(unique(as.character(x))%in% unique(y))
```

Thoughts on how to get this to identify the False indices (or in this example, 2)?

Comment: `which(!unique(as.character(x))%in% unique(y))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
which(!(unique(as.character(x))%in% unique(y)))
```

cdeeterman is basically correct, just need to make sure that the not (!) applies to the entire relation unique(as.character(x))%in% unique(y)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using two equal signs where "x == y" basically says "x is exactly equal to y"

```
x = c("a", "b", "c")
y = c("a", "z", "c")

z = x == y
which(z == FALSE)
```

Comment: Or simply `which(x != y)`

Answer (score 1):

What about setdiff?

```
> which( y %in% setdiff(y,x)  )
[1] 2
```